# How to stop Animation on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

When I scroll down my page three boxes appears on scrolling which is perfect. But when I scroll up my page those three boxes goes disappear and I will have to scroll down again for appearing those boxes. I just wanted to animate boxes only once, If I scroll up page, those boxes should not be disappear.

Link is here
http://www.shahfahad.com/scrol/demo/scrol.html

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle instead of posting your own website link

Answer (score 0):

set All boxes in on div

```html
<div class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-right">
        <div class="aos-item__inner"><h3>42</h3></div>
      </div>
      <div class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-left">
        <div class="aos-item__inner"><h3>42</h3></div>
      </div>

      <div class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="aos-item__inner"><h3>1</h3></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i want to put it in different "divs" is it possible different "divs" ?